# why does simply switching from Frame to JFrame cause such a big difference?

Tags: java, swing, awt

This code displays x and y points based on where you click. I want to add a JPanel so that the frame does not start measuring from the title bar which is unreachable to the user.

Every time I switch from Frame to JFrame I get this:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckq9a.png)

The previous click does not disappear... What is the easiest way to fix this or am i able to add a JPanel on a Frame?

Below is my code:

```
************************************************************/

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Proj07Runner {
  Proj07Runner(){
    System.out.println(
    "Terminal text");
    GUI gui = new GUI(); //instantiate a GUI
  }//end main
}

**Here is where switching from Frame to JFrame causes the change**
class MyFrame extends JFrame{
  int clickX;
  int clickY;

  public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString(
             "" + clickX + ", " + clickY, clickX, clickY);
  }//end paint()
}


class GUI {
  public GUI(){//constructor
    //Create a new JFrame object, set size, title, etc.
    MyFrame displayWindow = new MyFrame();
    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
    displayWindow.setSize(300,100);
    displayWindow.setTitle("Title");
    myPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));


    displayWindow.setVisible(true);
    //Instantiate and register an anonymous Listener;
    // object which will terminate the program when the;
    // user closes the JFrame.
    displayWindow.addWindowListener(new WProc1());

    myPanel.addMouseListener(
                             new MouseProc(displayWindow));
    displayWindow.addMouseListener(
                             new MouseProc(displayWindow));
                             
          
  }
}

//This listener class monitors for mouse presses and;
// displays the coordinates of the mouse pointer when the
// mouse is pressed on the source object. Note that this
// class extends is an adapter class.
class MouseProc extends MouseAdapter{
  MyFrame refToWin; //save a reference to the source here
  MouseProc(MyFrame inWin){//constructor
    refToWin = inWin;//save ref to window
  }//end constructor

  //Override the mousePressed method to determine and;
  // display the coordinates when the mouse is pressed.
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    //Get X and Y coordinates of mouse pointer and store
    // in an instance variable of the JFrame object
    refToWin.clickX = e.getX();
    refToWin.clickY = e.getY();
    //refToWin.clearRect(0,0,300,100);

    // Force the JFrame object to be repainted in order to
    // display the coordinate information.
    refToWin.repaint();
  }//end mousePressed()
}

//The following listener is used to terminate the program
// when the user closes the frame.  Note that this class
// extends an adapter class.
class WProc1 extends WindowAdapter{
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: JFrame is the swing framework, and Frame is the awt framework. You're essentially using two different UI implementations at that point (swing was an extension of awt). You definitely want `JFrame` if you are using swing in other components (e.g. `JPanel`)

Comment: What would be the best way to fix it? Is leaving it as Frame and using Panel instead of JPanel a good solution?

Comment: For one, you should still be calling `super.paint(g);` in your `#paint` method if it was overridden. Secondly, I wouldn't override the `#paint` of `JFrame`, but rather I would add a `TextComponent` to the `JPanel`, updating the position of it accordingly when a click is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates look awkward because the MouseListener is on the Frame, not the Panel. The coordinates will always be in the component's coordinate system that the listener is attached to.
So if you do the rendering in the JPanel, why not attach the MouseListener to that JPanel?

While AWT is a heavy weight UI framework (every AWT component has some native UI representation such as X Widget or a Windows 'window'), Swing is a lightweight framework. Only the root component JWindow, JFrame or JDialog have native representations, the rest is within the JVM. When mixing components you need to know about this difference.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit#Mixing_AWT_and_Swing_components
Ummmm, I just learned that the problem I was referring to may have been fixed since Java 6...

Somehow I felt like creating a small demo using Swing only:

```
package com.mycompany.test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel {
    
    private Point clickPosition;

    public TestPanel() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                clickPosition = e.getPoint();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (clickPosition != null) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawLine(clickPosition.x-5, clickPosition.y, clickPosition.x+5, clickPosition.y);
            g.drawLine(clickPosition.x, clickPosition.y-5, clickPosition.x, clickPosition.y+5);
            g.drawString(String.format("(%d, %d)", clickPosition.x, clickPosition.y), clickPosition.x+5, clickPosition.y-5);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(new TestPanel());
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```